# How to get mvc dropdown selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am working on a MVC project where I am doing CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete) operations on `Employee` objects.

Here's the problem: I am using a dropdown for `DepartmentName` to be assigned to the employee and when I edit the employee I want to get the selected value of the employee on the department dropdown which has be assigned to him earlier.

Here is the code:

Main view

```
<table class="table" id="Grid">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GenderName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GenderName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentName)
        </td>

        @if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');" })
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

DBHelper

```
public List<Emloyee> GetEmployees()
{
    connection();
    List<Emloyee> employeelist = new List<Emloyee>();


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmployeeDetails", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();


    con.Open();
    sd.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        employeelist.Add(
            new Emloyee
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
                Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]),
                GenderName = Convert.ToString(dr["GenderName"]),
                DepartmentName = Convert.ToString(dr["DepartmentName"])
            });
    }
    return employeelist;
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    EmployeeDB edb = new EmployeeDB();
    var depart = edb.GetDepartment();
    ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(depart, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");


    return PartialView(edb.GetEmployees().Find(cmodel => cmodel.Id == id));
}
```

Edit View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId",(SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentId, new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, nor what problems you're encountering.

Comment: i want the selected value of Department Name of employee in dropdown list on edit page .

Comment: Restating the same words as you used in your question does not make it clearer. Please read [ask].

Comment: Your employee model has only departmentName and in view your are referring "DepartmentId" . Add DepartmentId to your employee model. @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId",(SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentId, new { @class = "form-control" })

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier in comments, your Employee model doesn't contain `departmentId`, include `departmentId` in the model. I suspect that is the reason you are not able to view department on Edit View. I believe  below code snippet will fix the issue.

```
public List<Emloyee> GetEmployees()
{
    connection();
    List<Emloyee> employeelist = new List<Emloyee>();


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmployeeDetails", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();


    con.Open();
    sd.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        employeelist.Add(
            new Emloyee
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
                Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]),
                GenderName = Convert.ToString(dr["GenderName"]),
                DepartmentName = Convert.ToString(dr["DepartmentName"])
                DepartmentId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DepartmentId "])
            });
    }
    return employeelist;
}
```

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    EmployeeDB edb = new EmployeeDB();
    var depart = edb.GetDepartment();
    ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(depart, "DepartmentId", 
  "DepartmentName");


    return PartialView(edb.GetEmployees().Find(cmodel => cmodel.Id == id));
}
```

View :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId",(SelectList)ViewBag.Departments, new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the constructor to override the fourth parameter when the default value of `selectList`.

```
ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(depart, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName",[setYourDefaultValue]);
```

[SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)

**Edit**

You `DropDownList` need to set `SelectListItem` be a `null`

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId",null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You can see the source code on asp.net MVC `selectList`

If you use this override method.

```
DropDownList(HtmlHelper, String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, IDictionary<String, Object>)
```

You need to set `selectList` be null that can get default value.

```
private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata,
    string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool allowMultiple,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "name");
    }

    bool usedViewData = false;

    // If we got a null selectList, try to use ViewData to get the list of items.
    if (selectList == null)
    {
        selectList = htmlHelper.GetSelectData(name);
        usedViewData = true;
    }
    ....etc
}
```

[MVCSourceCode](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/62d0b2df0bcca848a8e0848fd1866928df15528e/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs)